# Windows Phone 7 Built in Sounds

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am building a timer app for Windows Phone 7 and want to use a built in alarm when the timer runs out. Is this possible or do I have to create my own sounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jaime Rodriguez wrote:

> Out of the box right now, it is not possible for you to reuse the sounds.  There is no way for a SL or XNA app to get to those sounds.
>
> I do like the idea of packaging the
>   sounds and letting developers use
>   them, similar to what we did for
>   icons.   Can't promise (so don't hold
>   me against it, but will send emails to
>   the right people and see what they
>   share.  Thanks for the suggestion.

You must create your own. Here are some [tips](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Jaime+Rodriguez/Windows-Phone-Design-Days-Audio)

Answer (score 0):

Search for SoundEffect, which is a XNA class, but you can import.
For Silverlight, you can use the class MediaElement, if you dont intend to use 2 sounds together. If you wish, then you will have to use SoundEffect.